# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "dbConnection" not found

Tags: php, forms, mysqli

I'm trying to use a function of my "Truck" class which extends "dbConnection" class but I keep getting error Class "dbConnection" not found.
I even tried including it still getting the same error.

The truck.php class:

```
<?php
    require_once './dbConnection.php';

    class Truck extends dbConnection{
    public $truckID;
    public $driverName;
    public $driverLastName;
    public $plateNum;
    public $availabilityCode;
        
    function getAllTrucks(){
    $sql= "SELECT * FROM truck";
            $result = $this->connect()->query($sql);
            $numRows = $result->num_rows;
            if($numRows>0){
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                    $data[] = $row;

                }
                return $data;
            }  }}?>
```

The dbConnection.php:

```
<?php
    class dbConnection {
        private $servername ;
        private $username ;
        private $password ;
        private $db;

        protected function connect(){
            $this->servername="localhost";
            $this->username="root";
            $this->password="";
            $this->db="smart_customer_services";
        
            $conn = new mysqli($this->servername,$this->username,$this->password,$this->db);
            return $conn;
        
        } 
}
?>
```

---

Where I'm calling it:

```
<?php
 $Trucks = new Truck();
 $allTrucks= array();
 $allTrucks= $Trucks->getAllTrucks();
?>
```

Comment: When you include an error message, include the complete text, not your edited version.

Answer (score -2):

Please try it without function i think it working

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "smart_customer_services";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM truck";
$result = $conn->query($sql);    
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
$conn->close();
```

Try With Function

```
// db concation
class dbConnection {     

    protected function connect(){
        $servername = 'localhost';
        $username = 'root';
        $password = '';
        $db = 'smart_customer_services';

        $conn = new MySQL($servername,$username,$password,$db);
        return $conn;
    } 
}



  class Truck extends dbConnection{   
        
    function getAllTrucks(){
require_once('dbConnection.php');
        $result=$db->query("select * from truck");   
        $numRows = $result->num_rows;
        if($numRows>0){
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            $data[] = $row;
            }
            return $data;
        } 

    } 

}
```

Comment: A Truck is not a database connection. require_once shouldn't be used in classes.